# Replacing strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Here's how you would replace all strings in your column that match:

```
x['Series'] = x['Series'].str.replace("IONIQ HYBRID", 'IONIQ_HYBRID', regex = True)
```

Comment: You're trying to use the result of a `str.replace` operation which will return a `Series` which will contain string data, as a boolean mask for a `df`, why would this work? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Well, you're trying to index the dataframe with a series, which doesn't really make sense, not sure what you're trying to obtain with that?

Comment: I am sorry, I am dumb.

x['Series'] = x['Series'].str.replace("IONIQ HYBRID", 'IONIQ_HYBRID', regex = True)